# Everything works except it asks user to input temperature and speed twice at the start of program

Tags: python-3.x

Everything works except it asks user to input temperature and speed twice at the start of program

```
#This program uses 2 functions to calculate the windchill from fahrenheit
#temperature and wind speed.  Keeps asking until user enters n for no.
def get_input():
    temperature=float(input("Enter the fahrenheit temperature: "))  #defines temperature
    speed=float(input("Enter the wind speed: "))  #defines windspeed
    return temperature, speed
get_input()
def calculate_windchill(temperature, speed):
    windchill=round(35.74+0.6215*temperature-35.75*speed**0.16+0.4275*temperature*speed**0.16,1)#defines windchill
    return windchill
answer='y'
while answer=='y': #keeps asking for inputs of temperature and windspeed until the user enters n 
    temperature, speed=get_input()
    windchill=calculate_windchill(temperature, speed)
    calculate_windchill(temperature, speed) #calls function 
    print("The windchill is: ", windchill)
    answer=input("Would you like to calculate another windchill? Enter 'y' or 'n': ")
```

Comment: After the definition of `get_input`, you're calling it for no reason.

Comment: on what line?dd

Comment: Before `def calculate_windchill`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to happen then don't call get_input() function.

```
#This program uses 2 functions to calculate the windchill from fahrenheit
#temperature and wind speed.  Keeps asking until user enters n for no.
def get_input():
    temperature=float(input("Enter the fahrenheit temperature: "))  #defines temperature
    speed=float(input("Enter the wind speed: "))  #defines windspeed
    return temperature, speed
def calculate_windchill(temperature, speed):
    windchill=round(35.74+0.6215*temperature-35.75*speed**0.16+0.4275*temperature*speed**0.16,1)#defines windchill
    return windchill
answer='y'
while answer=='y': #keeps asking for inputs of temperature and windspeed until the user enters n 
    temperature, speed=get_input()
    windchill=calculate_windchill(temperature, speed)
    calculate_windchill(temperature, speed) #calls function 
    print("The windchill is: ", windchill)
    answer=input("Would you like to calculate another windchill? Enter 'y' or 'n': ")
```

Just remove the get_input() function call at line 6

Comment: Oh okay, missed that.  Thank you both